# Why doesn't gradlew build use local cache in docker (bitbucket) pipeline?

Tags: docker, gradle, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using a bitbucket docker pipeline to validate my builds for an android app on push. One of my dependancies is a private package which I am hosting on another bitbucket repository. For builds on the user machine, I use Gradle's private maven repository plugin which can resolve my dependency with encrypted username and password.

This works well for developer machines, but I want to avoid hard coding usernames and passwords in the pipeline. Instead, since bitbucket support sshkeys across repositories for authentication, I have built in my pipeline script to clone the repository with the my private packages, and copy them over to the gradle cache. I have tried both:

/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mycompany

~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mycompany

as caches. The clone and copy work just fine as I can see the files in their respective directories in the cache with by adding an ls in the pipeline, but gradlew still tries to go to the internet (the other bitbucket repository) to resolve the dependancies, as if there is no cache. Further, i'm using gradle docker image gradle:3.4.1 (the version of gradle in my project level build.gradle file), but gradle build fails with a google() is not a function.

Gradlew build fails trying to resolve my package.pom file, with a lack of a username (because there is no gradle.properties in the pipeline). But why doesn't it use the cache, instead of trying to go to the repository?

I have tried the standard java:8 docker image, the gradle docker image up to 5.1.1, and i have tried copying the package files into various gradle caches in the docker image. I have also tried altering permissions with chmod 775 to no avail. I have also tried gradlew assembleDebug with the same results as gradlew build. I'm a bit new to gradle, docker and bitbucket so i'm not sure what is causing the issue.

```
  image: gradle:3.4.1

  pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
          - android-sdk

        script:        
          # Download and unzip android sdk
          - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
          - unzip -o -qq android-sdk.zip -d android-sdk

          # Define Android Home and add PATHs
          - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/android-sdk"
          - export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"

          # Download packages.
          - yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools"
          - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
          - yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"
          - yes | sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
          - yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
          - yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;instantapps"
          - yes | sdkmanager --licenses

          # Build apk
          - git clone git@bitbucket.org:myorg/myrepo.git
          - scp -r myrepo/com/mycomp/* /home/gradle/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mycomp
          #- gradle build
          - ./gradlew build 
          #- ./gradlew assembleDebug

definitions:
    caches:
      android-sdk: android-sdk
```

Gradlew build error:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.mycomp:mypackage:1.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.mycomp:mypackage:1.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://bitbucket.org/myorg/myrepo/raw/releases/com/mycomp/mypackage/1.0.11/package-1.0.1.pom'.
            > Username may not be null
```

Comment: I tried to run the build with offline specified:

./gradlew build --offline 

And I get the error:

> No cached version of com.mycomp:mypckge:1.0.1 available for offline mode.

I have the package by company name in:

 /home/gradle/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/

the same as on my local machine, and all of the other android and related packages are here as well. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: It looks like there is an open ticket on this on github. Gradle doesn't seem to acknowledge an offline cache unless it was cached by gradle itself:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1338